# Can I install and run pyenv-virtualenv without installing 'python-openssl' and 'tk-dev'

Tags: linux, apt, python, dependencies, mx-linux

System MX linux 21.3 on Macbook Pro 13 inch mid 2012. I want to install python 2 and python 2 packages alongside python 3. Therefore I proceeded to install and run pyenv-virtualenv. When I try to preinstall dependencies as suggested in [realpython](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) website(I used 'apt' in place of 'apt-get'),

> $ sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev 
> libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev 
> libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl

I could not proceed. I tried installing one by one. Only these two remained 'python-openssl' and 'tk-dev'. When I try to install them Konsole shows error

> dh-python: breaks: python
>
> ```
>         breaks: python:i386
> ```

How do I resolve this problem? Can I install and run pyenv-virtualenv without installing 'python-openssl' and 'tk-dev'? Do I need to uninstall dh-python? Do I install only pyenv and proceed from there?

Comment: Your Python installation comes with venv already. Why go the self-building detour?

Comment: I am only trying to install and use libinput gestures. libinput gestures needs python-gobject to have a gui. python-gobject needs python 2. dh-python is preventing python 2 from installing. I have no need for venv. Only that programs that are dependent on older versions of python should be able to be run. I also know not whether with pyenv this will be possible. Also I do not want to remove dh-python as I assume that it is the system provided python and  removing it will cause problems. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You're right to not remove dh-python! I don't know MX Linux well enough, but being a debianoid, I'd expect it to have a package called `python2`; I guess that doesn't work for some reason?

Comment: Also in very confused now, because [libinput-gestutes](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures/) needs python 3, not python 2. So all your attempts to install a different version of python take you nowhere.

Comment: In libinput-gestures page, 2 deps are listed wmctrl and xdotools. All of these install easily. But I cannot make them work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArBCfhVsTZw video gives the dependencies as "wmctrl python3 python3-setuptools xdotool python3-gi libinput-tools python-gobject. These packages will allow you to map gestures to specific key presses and to use an app for creating the gestures." The way I am getting it is that python-gobject is the thing that gives rise to the gui. I may be wrong. Also I think some of these packages need python 2 packages in a dep of dep of dep way

Comment: It may be possible to do the gesture mapping in a non-gui way in the config file, but I am not tech-savvy and I will not be able to do that in a thousand years.

Comment: Also gestures-Modern, minimal GUI app for libinput-gestures. https://gitlab.com/cunidev/gestures . deps python3 python3-gi python-gobject meson xdotool libinput-tools gettext.

Comment: You're wrong. Gobject is a general programming framework, and no, no python 3 module needs python 2 as indirect dependency.